# Ecto add many_to_many with extra fields

Tags: many-to-many, elixir, ecto

I followed this instruction http://blog.roundingpegs.com/an-example-of-many-to-many-associations-in-ecto-and-phoenix/ to create a many_to_many association. But I need some fields in the many_to_many table. users_organizations would need fields like left and joined_at in my case. So I need to add a model for my users_organizations with the extra fields. But how to work with them? Creating the organization -> create users_organization with the extra fields and put it with put_assoc to the organization? Does anyone hav an example for this case or could tell me if my approach is correct?

THX

Answer (score 1):

Seems Ectos many_to_many api does not support extra fields. Found it here: https://elixirforum.com/t/many-to-many-association-table-with-extra-columns/6563/4  And thanks for the downvote ;)